# Resolve promises in order of resolve/execution time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Almost every question that I've seen on this topic discusses how to resolve a sequence of promises **sequentially**.

However, I want to resolve them in order of finishing time.

For example:

```js
const files = [{
    name: 'test1.txt',
    fileContents: 'abasdadsjadas',
  },
  {
    name: 'test2.txt',
    fileContents: 'asldjknaisdha',
  },
  {
    name: 'test3.txt',
    fileContents: 'hifhdsfyads',
  },
  {
    name: 'test4.txt',
    fileContents: 'kjhakjhfjhagdsjhagdkaj',
  },
  {
    name: 'test5.txt',
    fileContents: 'kjasdhbasd',
  }
];

const uploadPromise = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(name), Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}


//Prints file names in order:
const filesInOrder = files.map(x => uploadPromise(x.name))
Promise.all(filesInOrder).then(x => console.log("In order: ", x))

//Print file names in order of resolve time
const logs = [];
files.forEach(x => logs.push(uploadPromise(x.name)))
logs.forEach(x => x.then(y => console.log(y))) // eg: test2.text, test3.text, test1.text, test5.text, test4.text
```

As you can see the way I print them in order of resolving time is incredibly ugly and hard to read. Is there something I'm missing on how to do it simply here? I'm having a brain freeze.

Comment: I guess what you have is ok, seems readable and straight forward (maybe missing a clarifying comment). I should point out though, that in both ways of processing the resolved promises doesn't exclude them resolving in the same order. `Promise.all` isn't resolving them in ***any*** specific order at all, but instead waits for ***all** promises to resolve *then* returns an array of resolved promises in the same order they were in originally. They are asynchronous and can resolve individually in any order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you might; handling each promise separately.

```js
finishedOrder = []
files1 = [{
    name: 'test1.txt',
    fileContents: 'abasdadsjadas',
  },
  {
    name: 'test2.txt',
    fileContents: 'asldjknaisdha',
  },
  {
    name: 'test3.txt',
    fileContents: 'hifhdsfyads',
  },
  {
    name: 'test4.txt',
    fileContents: 'kjhakjhfjhagdsjhagdkaj',
  },
  {
    name: 'test5.txt',
    fileContents: 'kjasdhbasd',
  }
];

uploadPromise1 = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(name), Math.random() * 1000)
  }).then(name => {
    console.log(`Finished ${name}`);
    finishedOrder.push(name);
  })
}


//Prints file names in order:
filesInOrder1 = files1.map(x => uploadPromise1(x.name))
Promise.all(filesInOrder1).then(x => console.log("Done", files1, finishedOrder))
```